# Contact the supervisory patent examiner (SPE)

Tags: utility, examination, examiner

I got a response from USPTO about my application:

The application is waiting to be assigned a examiner. The SPE has it right now and the SPE name is **** and the phone number is  (***)***-****.

My questions are, can I directly contact the spe?

Will the spe examine my application or he will handle the examination process with the examiner?

What is the next step for me now?

Thank you in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it looks like it has come off a queue and been assigned to an art unit. The SPE is the manager of the art unit and has the job to assign the examination to someone in that unit. There will be a queue to go through and then it will be assigned. Then it is in the queue of the specific examiner who will do the examination under the SPE's supervision.

Comment: Does the art unit handle the utility patents? Thank in advance for your answer.

Comment: The whole examining corp is organized into about a dozen Technology Centers, each of which has many smaller Art Units broken up by detailed subject matter definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Normally SPEs do not examine patent applications but are examined by PEs/AEs. PEs/AEs apprise, consult respective SPE and office action intimation are issued as suggested or advised by SPE. Your application in all likely hood is to be assigned to a PE as mentioned in the communication - **"The application is waiting to be assigned a examiner."**

For time being, it will be prudent to wait till application is assigned to examiner.

For a birds eye view about patent examination and examiners may refer [Ref1](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=ef96f684-f70e-4860-8bbd-84300761e3a6) and [Ref2](https://www.uspto.gov/help/patent-help)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it